# If f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is an open set in the range of $f$, then the set $f^{−1}(V) = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x)\in V\}$ is open.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

> Prove: If f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is an open set in the range of
>   $f$, then the set 
>   $$f^{−1}(V)=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)\in V \}$$ is open.

To illustrate $f^{−1}(V)$ if you’re having trouble understanding what it is, suppose $f(x)=x^2 $ and $ V =(−5,4)∪ (9,10)$. Then
$$f^{−1}(V)=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in (−5,4)\cup(9,10)\}=(−\sqrt{10},−3)\cup(−2,2)\cup(3,\sqrt{10})$$

I know that in order to prove something is open we must either prove that it's complement is not closed or that the set contains all it's interior points. However, I'm not sure how to start from the fact that f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is open in the range of $f$.

Comment: Are you using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity? (**Remark:** In topology, the definition that is usually considered is that $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is open whenever $V$ is.)

Comment: Hello. Yes, we are using the epsilon delta definition

Comment: OP, I think you're supposed to tag as follows: @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set is called the preimage of $V$ by $f$.

---

[image]

---

I'm guessing $$B(f(a),\varepsilon) = (f(a) - \varepsilon, f(a) + \varepsilon)$$

and $$B(a,\delta)=(a-\delta,a+\delta)$$

---

Source:

http://www3.nd.edu/~jiller/teaching/archive/fall14_20850/continuity.pdf

---

Another one that explains in detail (still Calculus style I think and not using topology except that $$d(x,y) = |x-y|$$)

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/easyanalysis1.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take any point $x\in f^{-1}(V)$, and let $y = f(x)\in V$. Use the definition of continuity to construct a ball around $x$ that is sent to a subset of a ball around $y$ that is completely contained in $V$. Use this to prove that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.